# How do I include base64 image in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I'm having a problem including a base64 image using `tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent',`

The following works:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand("mceInsertContent", true, "<img style = 'height:80px;width:80px' src='/Content/image.png' />");`

tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand("mceInsertContent", true, "<div>safasfdasfd</div>");
```

But when using `tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', true, img64);` 
where `img64` is a `base64` image received from a MVC partial view converted to string.

Does someone have a working example. I don't know if the syntax is wrong or if there is some option I have forgotten?

**Update:**

The following do not work:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand("mceInsertContent", true, "<img style='height:80px;width:80px' src='data:image/png;base64,/some long 64 string is here'>");
```

Does anyone know why this is not working? Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It'd likely have to be correct HTML, no? `<img src='data......` but I personally would send the image to the server and store it there temporarily, if at all possible

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Comment: Thanks! That's how it looks for me <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." /> and the image shows up ok outside of tinymce, if I put it for example in a div. But for some reason it won't work in tinymce.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that others are having this problem as well.  Until there is an official way to solve your problem, there is a workaround posted in this thread: https://github.com/buddyexpress/bdesk_photo/issues/2

**UPDATE:**  Solution is to add `paste_data_images : true` to your configuration.
See the docs here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:paste_data_images

Comment: I created a TinyMCE bug report for this.  Vote for it here: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=7549

Answer (score 0):

Try `mceInsertRawHTML` rather than `mceInsertContent`